How to write YAML config file for docker images
I am trying to automate a process using Java in which I am writing YAML config to a file.
While I am able to achieve most of it, I am stuck with the last part "links" and need help on this to solve this by recognising the appropriate datastructure for it. Also I want to understand where I am going wrong.
The Expected YAML is :
name: srlceos01
topology:
  nodes:
    srl:
      kind: nokia_srlinux
      image: ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
    ceos:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.25.0F
  links:
    - endpoints: ["srl:e1-1", "ceos:eth1"]

My understanding is "links" is an array of list of array of "endpoints". I am getting below result:
Actual Result:
!!xx.xx.xx.bean.Container (Unwanted and wanted to remove)
links:
  linkArray:
  - endpoints:
    - endpoints:
      - srl:e1-1
      - ceos:eth1
  - null
  - null
  - null
  - null
name: srlceos01
topology:
  srl:
    image: ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
    kind: nokia_srlinux

My code:
public class Container {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, Nodes> topology;
    private LinksArray links;

}

public class LinksArray {

    private Links[] linkArray;
}

public class Links {

    private List<Endpoint> endpoints;
}

public class Endpoint {

    private String[] endpoints;
}

public class Nodes {
    
        private String kind;
        private String image;
    }

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions.FlowStyle;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag;
import xx.xx.Container;

@Service
public class GenerateYamlFileImpl {

    public void writeYamlfile(Container yamlConfig) {

        DumperOptions dpo = new DumperOptions();
        dpo.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(dpo);
        System.out.println(yaml.dump(yamlConfig));
    }

}


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("xx.xx.xx")
public class EmulateGuiBackendApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(EmulateGuiBackendApplication.class, args);
GenerateYamlFile gf = new GenerateYamlFile();
gf.createYamlFile();
}
}




import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import xx.xx.Container;
import xx.xx.Endpoint;
import xx.xx.Links;
import xx.xx.LinksArray;
import xx.xx.Nodes;
import xx.xx.service.GenerateYamlFileImpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Component
public class GenerateYamlFile {

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GenerateYamlFile.class);


    public void createYamlFile() {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.setName("srlceos01");
        Map<String, Nodes> topo = new LinkedHashMap();
        Nodes node = new Nodes();
        node.setImage("ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux");
        node.setKind("nokia_srlinux");
        topo.put("srl", node);
        String[] link = {"srl:e1-1","ceos:eth1"};
        Endpoint end = new Endpoint();
        end.setEndpoints(link);
        List<Endpoint> endpointList = new ArrayList<>();
        endpointList.add(end);
        Links newLink = new Links();
        newLink.setEndpoints(endpointList);
        Links[] lkarray = new Links[5];
        lkarray[0]=newLink;
        LinksArray lArr = new LinksArray();
        lArr.setLinkArray(lkarray);
        container.setTopology(topo);
        container.setLinks(lArr);
        GenerateYamlFileImpl yamlService = new GenerateYamlFileImpl();
        yamlService.writeYamlfile(container);
    }
}


Can you please add the code that calls writeYamlfile and also contains the setup of your Container instance? Try to keep as minimal as possible and just use constants / literals to initialize it. You will also want to provide more code in your model classes to make them initializable. (Effectivly we need a [mre])

@cyberbrain... Added code. Although code may not be optimal at this point, I will    clean up again to write proper code. This is draft code to test the functionality.

I tried to reproduce your result with a small project, but unfortunately you still didn't provide enough code - especially the imports and necessary dependencies are lacking. I guessed that List, Map, ArrayList, LinkedHashMap are taken from package java.util, and that your method writeYamlFile belongs into a separate class GenerateYamlFileImpl, my IDE guessed org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions and org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml. But I still struggle with the Nodes class. Where does it come from?

@cyberbrain... Thank you for pointing out, I had missed adding the Nodes class earlier by mistake. I have added those details to the post.

Your class hierarchy does not properly model the YAML structure. Specifically, your LinksArray is not an array but a POJO, and Endpoint is superfluous.
What you need is this:
public class Container {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Nodes> topology;
    private List<Link> links;
}

public class Link {
    private List<String> endpoints;
}

As for omitting the root tag, do this:
DumperOptions dpo = new DumperOptions();
dpo.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
Representer representer = new Representer(dpo);
representer.addClassTag(Container.class, Tag.MAP);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer);

I preserved FlowStyle.BLOCK from your original code although that prevents you from getting ["srl:e1-1", "ceos:eth1"] – obviously you will get a block-style sequence instead. I assume that's what you want.

thank you. I was able to resolve that issue with your guidance but i am stuck with another issue. need help and the issue is related to old issue. As per my problem statement, I want to have both block and flow style in my yaml and I can't ignore that (due to some dependency on other app). And I bit clueless how i can i achieve in same yaml. The final yaml format I want to achieve is the expected format provided in the question - "Expected YAML"

The YAML spec requires that it makes no difference whether a value is flow-style or block-style. If your dependency doesn't do that it doesn't support YAML properly. That seems unlikely (I don't know of any YAML implementation that has this problem) so I advise to double-check whether your error with the dependency isn't actually something different.
